# How to update UIProgressView below navigation controller properly?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uiprogressview

My goal is progress bar below the navigation bar, which works absolutely fine as you can see on this screenshot:

[image]

Here is the code which creates this:

```
class NavigationController: UINavigationController {

    let progressView = UIProgressView(progressViewStyle: .Bar)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        progressView.progress = 0.9
        view.addSubview(progressView)

        let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: navigationBar, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: progressView, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 1)
        let leftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: navigationBar, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: progressView, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let rightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: navigationBar, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: progressView, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

        progressView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addConstraints([bottomConstraint, leftConstraint, rightConstraint])
        progressView.setProgress(0.8, animated: true)
    }
}
```

But when I am trying to update the progress value by pressing the upload button,

```
for value in [0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0] {
    NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(0.5)
    let navC = navigationController as! NavigationController // shorthand
    navC.progressView.setProgress(Float(value), animated: true)
    let isMainThread = NSThread.isMainThread() // yes, it is main thread
    let currentValue = navC.progressView.progress // yes, the value is updated
}
```

nothing happens, but for the last value `1.0` suddenly the progress is full. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var queue = dispatch_queue_create("a", nil)
dispatch_async(queue, {
    for value in [0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0] {
        NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(0.5)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            let navC = navigationController as! NavigationController // shorthand
            navC.progressView.setProgress(Float(value), animated: true)
        })
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try doing it on another thread so as to update it perfectly like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
           for value in [0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0] 
 {
    NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(0.5)
    let navC = navigationController as! NavigationController // shorthand
    navC.progressView.setProgress(Float(value), animated: true)
    let isMainThread = NSThread.isMainThread() // yes, it is main thread
    let currentValue = navC.progressView.progress // yes, the value is updated
 }    
});
```

Comment: Does not work. And why it should? UI related stuff has to run in the main thread.